# Kotlin Version Incompatibility Error in Android Studio: Metadata 1.9.0 expected, but 1.6.0 found

Tags: android, kotlin

I am facing a Kotlin version conflict issue in my multi-module Android project. When attempting to build, I receive the following error:

`.gradle/caches/transforms-3/d03e801dea1b3ff22428c51c576b323b/transformed/jetified-agent-android-8.283.1.1004-api.jar!/META-INF/agent.instrumentorAPI.compose_release.kotlin_module: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0.`

My project consists of several modules (`profile`, `survey`, `app`), each with its own `build.gradle` file. In the project-level `build.gradle`, I have set the Kotlin version to 1.6.0:

````
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
}```


However, I am facing an issue where the module seems to require Kotlin 1.9.0. Here are some key details of my setup:

Android Studio version: [Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 3]
Kotlin version: 1.6.0 (as specified in the project's build.gradle)
Gradle version: [7.0.4]



I tried fixing a Kotlin version conflict in my project by clearing the Gradle cache, both via Android Studio and manually in the .gradle folder, restarting Android Studio, and aligning Kotlin versions across all modules. Despite these efforts, the error 'Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.9.0, expected version is 1.6.0' still appears, suggesting unresolved issues in project configuration or dependencies.

Could anyone advise on resolving this conflict without upgrading to Kotlin 1.9.0, despite having Kotlin 1.6.0 set in the project-level build.gradle?

Thanks in advance for any insights or suggestions!

Best regards.
````

Comment: hey @cesar did you find any fix?, am also facing the issue.

Comment: Yes, @Chris answer helped me. If you have Dynatrace implemented. The version that helped me is `com.dynatrace.agent:agent-android:8.237.1.1004''com.dynatrace.agent:agent-android:8.237.1.1004`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

8.283.1.1004 is the version of dynatrace. Fall back to last version if you don't want to upgrade to 1.9.0

Answer (score 1):

You will need to downgrade you dynatrace version. Generally it happens when you use plus sign for automatic gradle versioning such as 'com.dynatrace.tools.android:gradle-plugin:8+'

Answer (score 0):

As @Chris said, the last version of Dynatrace did the problem, you can fall back to the penultimate version **8.279.1.1002**